# PHP Login Script is not working with salts..how to solve it

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am building a login form which also supports hashing with salts.

I have completed the login form but in my login form, when user doesn't provide password, he is redirected to welcome page & when user submits password, error occurs saying incorrect password even though the submitted password is correct.

Below is my login form:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $email        = $_POST['email'];
    $userPassword = $_POST['password'];
    $query        = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE (email='$email')";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('mysql error');
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $get_user_details = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $user_id          = strip_tags($get_user_details['user_id']);
        $db_password      = strip_tags($get_user_details['password']);
        $salt             = strip_tags($get_user_details['salt']);
        $sr_user_sub_pass = hash('sha512', $userPassword . $salt);
        if ($user_sub_pass == $db_password) {
            header("location: welcome.php");
        } else {
            echo 'incorrect password';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'user not found';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: **YOU ARE VULNERABLE TO SQL INJECTION!** That makes it almost irrelevant that the hashing is not working.

Comment: You are also using an obsolete database API. Use mysqli or PDO. There's also no point whatsoever in using `strip_tags`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see you declare the `$user_sub_pass` variable anywhere. That could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`if ($user_sub_pass == $db_password)`

To

`if ($sr_user_sub_pass === $db_password)`

---

As the others pointed out your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.
Use parametrized queries and you won't have to use `strip_tags()`, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Also `mysql` is deprecated so you should you use `mysqli*`or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the variable

```
$user_sub_pass
```

should be

```
$sr_user_sub_pass
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: I have changes that ...but still the problem persist